# NSView: setFrameOrigin and setFrameSize - what is causing inconsistent behaviour in this code?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsview

I have created a simplified example. I imagine if someone experienced runs this they will easily be able to explain this behaviour...

In the example the addView button creates a new child subview each time it is pressed. These subviews should be the same each time one is generated but it is only when the third subview has been generated that I get the correct result. What is the reason for this?

If you uncomment the repetition of the frame and bounds calls in the drawRect method you get the correct result on the second attempt - again I cannot explain  this behaviour.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    let parentView = ParentView(frame: NSRect(x: 100, y: 10, width: 100, height: 400))
    let yMax = 400
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(parentView)
    }

    @IBAction func addView(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let childView = ChildView(frame: NSRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        self.parentView.addSubview(childView)
        
        for v in parentView.subviews {
            print("subview frame: ", v.frame)
        }
        
    }
    
}

class ParentView: NSView {
    
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        
        guard let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else {
            return
        }
        drawRect(ctx: context)
    }
    
    func drawRect(ctx: CGContext) {
        let parentFrameMarker = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 400)
        ctx.addRect(parentFrameMarker)
        ctx.setStrokeColor(CGColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0))
        ctx.setLineWidth(1.0)
        ctx.strokePath()
    }
    
}

class ChildView: NSView {
    
    let controller = ViewController()
    
    
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        
        guard let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else {
            return
        }
        
        let y = controller.yMax
        resizeView(y: y)
        drawRect(ctx: context, y: y)
        
    }
    
    func drawRect(ctx: CGContext, y: Int) {
        let width = 20
        let height = 40
//      let currentY = y - height
//
//      let origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: currentY)
//      let size = NSSize(width: width, height: height)
//      self.setBoundsSize(size)
//      self.setFrameSize(size)
//      print("new frame: ", self.frame)
//      print("new bounds: ", self.bounds)
//      self.setFrameOrigin(origin)
        
        let childFrameMarker = NSRect(x:0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
        print("childFrameMarker size: ", childFrameMarker.size)
        ctx.addRect(childFrameMarker)
        ctx.setStrokeColor(CGColor(red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0))
        ctx.setLineWidth(2.0)
        ctx.strokePath()
        
    }
    
    func resizeView(y: Int) {
        let width = 20
        let height = 40
        let currentY = y - height
        let origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: currentY)
        let size = NSSize(width: width, height: height)
        self.setBoundsSize(size)
        self.setFrameSize(size)
        self.setFrameOrigin(origin)
        print("new frame: ", self.frame)
        print("new bounds: ", self.bounds)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AppKit does not expect you to change a view's frame inside its `draw(_:)` method.

When you click the button to add a subview, that's an event. AppKit handles each event like this, **in this order**:

1. Call the callback for the event. In this case, the callback is your `addView(_:)` method.
2. Call `updateConstraints` on any view that has `needsUpdateConstraints` set. Note that a newly-created view automatically sets `needsUpdateConstraints`.

   If a view needs to make a bunch of changes to autolayout constraints, it's a little more efficient to do it in `updateConstraints` than in the event callback. If you're only changing a small number of constraints, don't worry about it.
3. Call `layout` on any view that has `needsLayout` set. Note that a newly-created view automatically sets `needsLayout`.

   By the time AppKit calls `layout`, it has already updated the frame of the receiving view. The receiving view's `layout` method is responsible for updating the frames of the view's subviews, but not of the view itself. The `NSView` implementation of `layout` updates the frames of subviews based on autolayout constraints, so it's generally important to call `super.layout()` if you override the `layout` method.
4. Call `draw(_:)` on any view that has `needsDisplay` set or that has any invalid regions due to calls to `setNeedsDisplay(_:)`. Note that a newly-created view automatically marks its entire bounds as invalid.

   By the time AppKit calls `draw(_:)`, it has already updated the frame of the view being drawn.

All calls to `updateConstraints` are made before any calls to `layout`, and all calls to `layout` are made before any calls to `draw(_:)`. By the time AppKit calls `draw(_:)`, it expects your views to have their correct frames and doesn't expect those frames to change until another event happens.

So the problem in your code is that you're not updating the frame of each `ChildView` when AppKit expects you to. You should be updating it in `layout`, but you're updating it in `draw(_:)`.

Another weird thing about your code is that each `ChildView` creates its own instance of `ViewController`, just to access the controller's `yMax` property. I think you probably want to either make the `yMax` property `static` so you can access it without an instance, or you want each `ChildView` to access the existing `ViewController`. But since it's really `ParentView`'s job to lay out each `ChildView`, it is `ParentView` that needs a reference to the existing `ViewController`.

Here's how I might write your code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    let parentView = ParentView(frame: NSRect(x: 100, y: 10, width: 100, height: 400))
    let yMax = 400

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        parentView.controller = self
        self.view.addSubview(parentView)
    }

    @IBAction func addView(_ sender: Any) {
        let childView = ChildView(frame: NSRect(x:0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
        parentView.addSubview(childView)
        parentView.needsLayout = true
    }
}

class ParentView: NSView {

    weak var controller: ViewController?

    override func layout() {
        super.layout()

        guard var y = controller?.yMax else { return }

        for subview in subviews {
            y -= 40
            subview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: 20, height: 40)
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        // No call to `super.draw(_:)` needed because ParentView is a direct subclass of NSView.
        NSColor.red.set()
        bounds.frame()
    }
}

class ChildView: NSView {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        NSColor.green.set()
        bounds.frame(withWidth: 2)
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

You commented:

> I am calculating geometries in draw and I use `setFrameOrigin` and `setFrameSize` to adjust the frame if needed depending on what needs to be drawn. I guess it would be possible to calculate the geometry of the 'drawing' before an instance of `ChildView` is created and then instantiate with the correct frame.  what a `ChildView` needs to draw would not actually be in the `ChildView` class. Any advice on this chicken and egg problem?”

Compute and store that information in `ChildView` as needed.

Let's say we want `ChildView` to draw a regular polygon. We want to specify the number of sides and the circumradius of the polygon, and then have `ChildView` laid out to perfectly fit the polygon. Here's a way to do it:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    let parentView = ParentView(frame: NSRect(x: 100, y: 10, width: 100, height: 400))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(parentView)
    }

    @IBAction func addView(_ sender: Any) {
        let childView = ChildView(
            sideCount: parentView.subviews.count + 3,
            radius: 30
        )
        parentView.addSubview(childView)
        parentView.needsLayout = true
    }
}

class ParentView: NSView {
    override func layout() {
        super.layout()

        var y = bounds.size.height

        for subview in subviews.lazy.compactMap({ $0 as? ChildView }) {
            let size = subview.intrinsicContentSize
            y -= size.height
            subview.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        // No call to `super.draw(_:)` needed because ParentView is a direct subclass of NSView.
        NSColor.red.set()
        bounds.frame()
    }
}

class ChildView: NSView {
    // Here is the raw data on which my appearance depends.
    var sideCount: Int { didSet { invalidate() } }
    var radius: CGFloat { didSet { invalidate() } }

    // Here is cached layout information that depends on my raw data.
    private var detailCache: Detail? = nil

    private struct Detail {
        var size: CGSize
        var vertices: [CGPoint]
    }

    init(sideCount: Int, radius: CGFloat) {
        self.sideCount = sideCount
        self.radius = radius

        super.init(frame: .zero)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError() }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { detail.size }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let vertices = detail.vertices
        guard let first = vertices.first else { return }
        let path = NSBezierPath()
        path.move(to: first)
        for p in vertices.dropFirst() {
            path.line(to: p)
        }
        path.close()
        NSColor.green.set()
        path.fill()
    }

    private func invalidate() {
        detailCache = nil
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        superview?.needsLayout = true
        needsDisplay = true
    }

    private var detail: Detail {
        if let detail = detailCache { return detail }
        let detail = makeDetail()
        detailCache = detail
        return detail
    }

    private func makeDetail() -> Detail {
        guard sideCount > 0 else { return Detail(size: .zero, vertices: []) }

        var vertices: [CGPoint] = []
        var pMin = CGPoint(x: CGFloat.infinity, y: .infinity)
        var pMax = CGPoint(x: -CGFloat.infinity, y: -.infinity)
        for i in (0 ..< sideCount).lazy.map({ CGFloat($0) }) {
            let p = CGPoint(
                x: radius * cos(2 * .pi * i / CGFloat(sideCount)),
                y: radius * sin(2 * .pi * i / CGFloat(sideCount))
            )
            vertices.append(p)
            pMin.x = min(pMin.x, p.x)
            pMin.y = min(pMin.y, p.y)
            pMax.x = max(pMax.x, p.x)
            pMax.y = max(pMax.y, p.y)
        }

        for i in vertices.indices {
            vertices[i].x -= pMin.x
            vertices[i].y -= pMin.y
        }

        return Detail(
            size: CGSize(
                width: pMax.x - pMin.x,
                height: pMax.y - pMin.y
            ),
            vertices: vertices
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: While this answers his question, I don't see this as a good reply. This is a slippery slope. You have a reference to a ViewController instance in your ParentView. A view should never know anything about it's controller. The way to go, is to create independent views and use autolayout to size and position your views.

Comment: It would be better to pass the `yMax` value down to `ParentView` but I didn't want to change the relationships between the objects more than necessary. Note that a lot of developers prefer to “manually” lay out views either for performance or because autolayout's behavior can be difficult to understand. Apple explicitly supports the manual style, and has in fact improved their support of it since autolayout was first introduced.

Comment: My issue, which led me to try and use setFrameOrigin and setFrameSize, is that at the point a subview is created, I do not yet know what its frame should be, and this can't be done at the 'Parent' level because the parent has no information about what this size should be either. I am calculating geometries in draw and I use setFrameOrigin and setFrameSize to adjust the frame if needed depending on what needs to be drawn. I guess it would be possible to calculate the geometry of the 'drawing' before an instance of ChildView is created and then instantiate with the correct frame...

Comment: ...from the start, but this would mean all of the logic around what a ChildView needs to draw would not actually be in the ChildView class. Any advice on this chicken and egg problem?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you thank you. So, in your solution it looks like it is the call to needsLayout on parentView that triggers the update of the detail variable on the subview - why does this work? Also, it is then only after this, finally, that draw is called on the subview. How is it that it is only at this point that this draw method gets called? Cheers!

Comment: I don't know how to explain "why" or "how" other than to say: this is the order that AppKit does things.

Answer (score 1):

There are no layout constraints on either of your views. You cannot position your views with coordinates.

You should look into autolayout.

When you are using autolayout, everything is controlled by the intrinsic content size of the view and the content hugging and compression resistance priority.

So you need to override the intrinsic content size of the view and use autolayout for the child view with layout constraints in relation to the parent view.
You should also remove all code in your drawRect, that tries to control the position or width/height of the view.

Only do drawing in the drawRect method.

Currently AppKit is adding ambiguous autolayout constraints for you automatically. It doesn't have enough information to place them correctly. That is what you are seeing.

Comment: It's fine to update a view's ”coordinates” (frame) as long as your changes don't conflict with any constraints on the view. A view created in code, as in this question, has `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set automatically, which means that the system expects you to set the frame directly.

Comment: There's no information that tells us if auto layout is in effect. The modern way to handle this is to use auto layout. If auto layout was used to position the button, it is fair to assume autolayout was used to position the parent view. Either way auto layout should be used in a modern application.

Comment: ”There's no information that tells us if auto layout is in effect.” Yes, there is. The code shown in the question doesn't create any constraints or turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`, so we know the views `frame`s and `autoresizingMask`s are converted to constraints automatically. This comment appears above `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` in the header file: ”by default, the autoresizing mask on a view gives rise to constraints that fully determine the view's position.  To do anything interesting with constraints, you need to turn that off. IB will turn it off.”